# Replacing less occurring as Others

Tags: python-3.x, replace

Replacing less occurring as Others.

In one of the column, i.e "Name" of the data frame say df, I have the data as below:

**Sample Input:**

Name

A

A

A

B

B

C

D

```
df['Name'].value_counts()


A      3
B      2
C      1
D      1
```

I would need output in below format.

**Expected output:**

```
A   3

B   2

Others 2
```

Any code in python3 is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
x = list(df['name'].value_counts()[:2].index)  # This will fetch top N values
df['name'] = np.where(df['name'].isin(x), df['name'], 'others')

print(df['Name'].value_counts())
```

**output**

```
A         3
B         2
others    2
```